# Why does sometimes the pseudo class is a:active and sometimes a.active?

Tags: pseudo-class

I see that in some templates the a:active pseudoclass is written a.active (with a Dot instead of Colon... Is it a class? Why would someone make a pseudocalls a class?... Is it really a good-practice? I'm sorry if this question is too simple to you, it's just the literature I read didn't give answer for that specific question I know have... Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.active` is not a pseudoclass. It's just a class `active` applied to the element. Someone might add the class when some element is active, and it doesn't have to be analog with the `:active` pseudoclass.

Active is such a common term that it may mean anything. It doesn't have to be related at all to a link being in an 'active' state.

In some cases they would be related, but someone may add a class because the pseudoclass isn't fit for the purpose.

For instance, one might want to show something (like a hint) when an element is hovered, but not hide it immediately when it is unhovered. So to do that, one can add a class when the element is hovered, and set a timer to remove it when the element is unhovered so there is a small delay.

The reason why you won't find this in literature is because they are essentially unrelated.

As requested, I've added a little snippet that shows the simplicity of the pseudoclass and the flexibility of adding your own classes.

```js
$(function(){
  // NONJS: Set a class from Javascript, so you can add different styling based on having JS or not.
  $('body').removeClass('nonjs').addClass('js');
  
  // The actual hover code for delayed hovering.
  $('.text.delayed').hover(
    
    // When hovered, add the class.
    function (){ $(this).addClass('hovered'); },
    
    // When unhovered, remove the class after a little time.
    function (){ 
       var element = this; 
       setTimeout(function(){
           $(element).removeClass('hovered');
         }, 2000);
    }
    
  );
});
```

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
}

.hint {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

/* Simple hints are just shown on hover, hidden when unhovered. */
.simple:hover .hint,
/* delayed hints are shown as long as they have the hovered class. */
.js .delayed.hovered .hint,
/* NONJS: Fallback for non-javascript situation, make delayed hint behave like simple hint using pure CSS. */
.nonjs .delayed:hover .hint
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body class='nonjs'>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text simple">Simple. Hover for more information
  <div class="hint">This is a simple hint which disappears immediately when unhovered.</div>
</div>

<div class="text delayed">Delayed. Hover for more information
  <div class="hint">This is a delayed hint which will remain visible for 2 seconds and is then hidden using Javascript.</div>
</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand your answer... Could you simplify it a bit and give an example to a state when a Themer will choose to create a class with this name? - In what cases does it necessary?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: I now understand that it's actually just a class name (that could be any other name for that matter) and that only sometimes they will be realted (I would in any case pick another name)... But I didn't understand the example - I mean hints are more of a Javascript issue... Could you bring something more HTML-CSS like? This would finally fill my gap. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added a snippet about the hover example, since I think that's more clear and easier to show. The snippet shows a simple, pure CSS hint that shows and hides using the `:hover` pseudoclass. The second text shows a hint using JavaScript which is hidden after two seconds after the element is unhovered. I threw in a complimentary non-JavaScript fallback for the JavaScript version (lines marked with 'NONJS'), but you can safely ignore that if you think it's confusing.

Comment: Ran the snippet, saw the hover (and hovering) of the text... If I understand correct, the "Active" class could serve as stylesheet for the hovered text (i.e give this "active"\"hovered" text some style).

Comment: Exactly. But also, possibly, to find 'active' elements and attach some JavaScript functionality to it. I haven't done that in the snippet, but you get the idea.